# Error - Recursive function calls by passing lists - OCaml

Tags: ocaml

I am trying to create permutations of strings contained in a list in OCaml.
I have worked on the following snippet of code till now but am facing a problem passing the first string of the list to my method.

Logic for code:
Iterate to every element of a list and append each element with element of the list. Continue doing till all the elements have been appended to the list in every possible position.

Code:

```
(* this function appends each string to each word in the list example: "A" with "ABC" *)
let appendtocode n word =
    let f x = n ^ x in
    f word    
;;

(* this function extracts every element of the list and appends it with the string.
Example: "A" with ["AAA","ABC","ACD"] etc.. *)
let appendtolist n list =
    let f x =
        if (List.length list) > 0 then list
        else ((appendtocode n (List.hd list)) ^ (appendtolist n (List.tl list)) ) 
    in
    List.map f list
;;
```

Error:

I get this error:

**Unbound value appendtolist**

Occurs at call to : (appendtolist n List.tl list)

My list is only consisting of string.
I am still working on the code. But stuck at this because of this error.

Please help!!! Any input would be great.

Comment: Why is this tagged sml and smlnj if you're using ocaml?

Comment: I fixed the tags, since this is definitely OCaml and has no obvious connection to SML.

Comment: thank you. and i apologize for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call the function recursively, you need to define it with `let rec appendtolist` rather than just `let appendtolist`.

You will then get a different error, because there are other bugs in your code ...

Answer (score 1):

You're getting the "Unbound value appendtolist" error because you're calling `appendtolist` recursively without declaring as recursive.

You need to write `let rec appendtolist n list = ...` to be able to refer to `appendtolist` recursively within its definition.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know SML well, but I think you need some more parens, e.g.

```
else ((append-to-code n List.hd list) ^ (append-to-list n List.tl list) )
```

should be

```
else ((append-to-code n (List.hd list)) ^ (append-to-list n (List.tl list)) )
```

Comment: This was indeed necessary; it wasn't producing the error message you were getting, but it would have caused an error at the next stage of typechecking.